# My code is returning the correct string, but there is a "None" in the middle

Tags: python

The first block of code returns the following :
"Your BMI is x.
None, You are y"

I am unsure why none is appearing, i can work around it using the commented code below, but i  want to know why this way does not work.

edited in a line i forgot to copy across

```
height = float(input("enter your height in m: "))
weight = float(input("enter your weight in kg: "))

bmi = round(weight / height **2)
bmi_print = print(f"Your BMI is {bmi}.")

if bmi <= 18.5:
  print(f"{bmi_print}, You are underweight.")
elif bmi <= 25:
  print(f"{bmi_print}, You are a normal weight.")
elif bmi <= 30:
  print(f"{bmi_print}, You are slightly overweight.")
elif bmi <= 35:
  print(f"{bmi_print}, You are obese.")
else:
  print(f"{bmi_print}, You are clinically obese.")
```

I can work around it if I do it the way below, but i wanted to know why the above way does not work

```
# if bmi <= 18.5:
#   print(f"Your BMI is {bmi}. You are underweight.")
# elif bmi <= 25:
#   print(f"Your BMI is {bmi}. You are a normal weight.")
# elif bmi <= 30:
#   print(f"Your BMI is {bmi}. You are slightly overweight.")
# elif bmi <= 35:
#   print(f"Your BMI is {bmi}. You are obese.")
# else:
#   print(f"Your BMI is {bmi}. You are clinically obese.")
```

Comment: It would be better to hard code values for height and weight, then post the output of the script. We shouldn't have to guess what the input should be or what the result should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
bmi_print = print(f"Your BMI is {round(bmi)}.")
```

To:

```
bmi_print = f"Your BMI is {round(bmi)}."
```

`print` function returns `None`. So, when you print that, it's printing `None`.

Answer (score 0):

`print(f"Your BMI is {bmi}.")` prints the string and returns `None`. you then assign that `None` to `bmi_print`. Its the same as if you did

```
print(f"Your BMI is {bmi}.")
bmi_print = None
```

`print` always returns `None`. Its job is to write its output to some file like object. It may not even build the entire string, choosing to emit its resultant string in chunks.